# Is it possible to install WordPress multisite in a Bitnami MAMP stack?

Tags: wordpress, mediawiki, wiki, mamp, bitnami

I am using Bitnami's MAMP stack for local development of WordPress and MediaWiki in OSX, but I need one stack with WordPress *multisite* and MediaWiki installed. Bitnami's site has an installer for WordPress multisite (http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress) but that is for a standalone stack, the only module they have there is for regular WordPress. Just enabling multisite in wp-config on that install does not work. 
Is there anyway to accomplish this? Could I do a standalone install of WordPress Multisite, move it into the MAMP stack's apps folder and set the appropriate mySQL settings in wp-config?

Comment: can you show us error: 'doesn't work' isn't something we can work from'?

Comment: If I enable multisite (in WP-config) on the regular wordpress stack, when I load Wordpress I get an error telling me that multisite is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. Try to install the WordPress Multisite Stack and then the Mediawiki module on top of it. I hope it helps.

Comment: I was about to reply and say this didn't work either. Now I realize I did it backwards (installed the WP multisite module and added the  media wiki module. I will try it in the order you suggested and report back.

Comment: @JPollock any news? I am in a similar situation (need wordpress multisite + mediawiki on the same LAMP bitnami stack) and was fishing for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress/ goto the Amazon Machine Images section. Select your region then click the ami link under Ubuntu EBS 32-bit